# Convert BMP to PNG while preserving alpha channel

Tags: images, imagemagick

I have an image stored in BMP format and would like to convert it to PNG using imagemagick.

I looked at the pixels in a hex viewer and noticed that they are stored in 32bpp, so there is an alpha channel. The transparent pixels have RGBA value (255, 255, 255, 0), and paint.NET is picking them up as white pixels probably because it doesn't expect BMP's to have transparent pixels?

Anyways, the command I used is

```
convert -alpha on -quality 95 in.bmp out.png
```

However, when I opened the resulting image in Paint.NET (which usually interprets transparent pixels properly), those transparent pixels were still white.

Am I converting the images incorrectly? I would like the pixels with an alpha value of 0 to appear transparent in the image editor that I commonly use.

Answer (score 5):

You discovered a bug in ImageMagick. This will be fixed in ImageMagick 6.8.7-9. I am one of the developers for ImageMagick and I just committed the fix to our SVN repository (http://trac.imagemagick.org/changeset/13867).

Comment: How do you know this?  Any supporting info?

Comment: I apologize for the short answer. I am one of the developers for ImageMagick and I just committed the fix to our SVN repository.

Comment: @dlemstra - that information would be better edited into your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out when it's released and get back to this question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity @Keikoku is there a link to the SVN repo we could see? Thanks for taking the time to provide this information, and for accurately disclosing your involvement with the project.

Comment: Don't know if @dlemstra gets a notification for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be an alpha channel.  If it's a bitmap v4 format file, it can have an alpha channel. For earlier versions, it is still possible to store the pixels as 32 bits, but the top bit is reserved and [always zero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here's an example of a 32 bit bmp with [alpha](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3nw4t3jhx7t6l8/alpha.bmp)
Here's an example of a 32 bit bmp with [no alpha](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7emz4p8f2fakgs/noalpha.bmp)

The example image in the comments has no alpha channel according to GIMP and `identify -verbose` the best you can do is make the white background transparent with

```
convert sample.bmp -transparent white alpha.png
```

Comment: I believe it is used as an alpha channel because not every pixel has zero for that byte, and if I parse it manually and treat it as an alpha channel, the resulting image has the correct transparent pixels. In that case, maybe imagemagick is not treating it as an alpha channel, so I would like to tell imagemagick to treat it as such?

Comment: Can you run `identify -verbose` on the file and look at the channel info? or post a link to the image itself

Comment: I made a BMP with alpha (with GIMP) and did convert alpha.bmp alpha.png and it worked ok.  The png was transparent.

Comment: here is a [sample bmp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cyfefda88xlyo1c/sample.zip).

Comment: According to GIMP and identify, there is no alpha channel

Comment: It may be missing data in the header. Does this mean it's not possible to tell imagemagick to treat the the 4th byte as an alpha channel?

Comment: Someone else had the same issue and reported it on the [imagemagick forums](http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15880), but it doesn't look like there were any resolutions either. Since the BMP format does not support alpha anyways it probably makes sense. I'd have to write my own tool to convert the BMP assuming the 4th byte contains an alpha channel.

Comment: BMP does support alpha, but it has to be the right version.  I've added 2 examples to my answer, both are 32 bit but only one has an alpha channel.

Comment: A few notes: • parkydr’s samples use only `00` and `FF` for all of the colors, probably because they’re paletteized • parkydr’s samples don’t show thumbnails in Explorer (XP) in 16px mode • Keikoku’s sample does show a 16px thumbnail • Keikoku’s sample is [*transparent*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JZb6K.png) in 16px mode (16px=icons) • [none are transparent in large mode](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7v5Pf.png) (that’s normal for XP) • you must download the samples from DropBox; the preview is converted to JPG • it is difficult to determine what BMP version a file is (IrfanView for one doesn’t say).